# Anyone know whats wrong with my code. Its not displaying anything in the console

Tags: javascript

Getting the average grade and displaying the letter grade accordingly

```
const grade = [70, 90, 50] / 3;

switch (grade) {
    case grade < 60:
        console.log("F");
        break;

    case grade >= 60 && grade < 70:
        console.log("D");
        break;

    case grade >= 70 && grade < 80:
        console.log("C");
        break;

    case grade >= 80 && grade < 90:
        console.log("B");
        break;

    case grade >= 100:
        console.log("Congrats on your A!");
}
```

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: `[70, 90, 50] / 3` is `NaN`; `grade < 60` and related conditions are booleans. A boolean will never be equal to `NaN`. Please read about [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and how [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) works.

Comment: What is `const grade = [70, 90, 50] / 3;` meant to do? Because what it actually does is set `grade` to `NaN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `const grade = [70, 90, 50] / 3;` returns `NaN` So other condition with switch case will not work as you expected. I think you want to achieve this after calculating the average of the 3 subjects. You can find the sum of 3 subjects using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and Then use **switch...case** syntax properly. See more about [switch-case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

So try like this way,

```js
const grade = [70, 90, 50].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / 3;

switch (true) { // see this line
  case grade < 60:
    console.log("F");
    break;
  case grade >= 60 && grade < 70:
    console.log("D");
    break;
  case grade >= 70 && grade < 80:
    console.log("C");
    break;
  case grade >= 80 && grade < 90:
    console.log("B");
    break;
  case grade >= 100:
    console.log("Congrats on your A!");
}
```

**OR** Less typing with [if..else if](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) version without using `break;` though.

```js
const grade = [70, 90, 50].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / 3;

if(grade < 60)
    console.log("F");
else if (grade >= 60 && grade < 70)
    console.log("D");
else if (grade >= 70 && grade < 80)
    console.log("C");
else if (grade >= 80 && grade < 90)
    console.log("B");
else if (grade >= 100)
    console.log("Congrats on your A!");
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the average, you need to first add all the values in the array together before dividing them by the amount of grades there is:

```
const average = grades.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0) / grades.length;
```

After that, you should use if/else-if blocks instead of switch to compare the values.

```js
const grades = [70, 90, 50]
const average = grades.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0) / grades.length;

console.log(average)


if (average < 60) console.log("F");
else if (average < 70) console.log("D");
else if (average < 80) console.log("C");
else if (average < 90) console.log("B");
else console.log("Congrats on your A!");
```

You don't need to check for the prior condition not applying (`average >= 60 &&` and so on), since this uses `else id`, this also means that you don't need to specify a condition for the `A` grade, since all other conditions don't aplly.

Comment: There's no need for the `average >= 60 && ` and such, you're using `else if`.

Answer (score 0):

If you put expressions in the `case` labels, then the `switch` value needs to be `true` or `false` (usually `true`).

That said, while you *can* put expressions in the `case` labels (in JavaScript, unlike many other languages), `if...else if...else` is more common.

Additionally, this line:

```
const grade = [70, 90, 50] / 3;
```

...sets `grade` to `NaN`, because the `/` coerces the array to a number, which goes by way of converting it to a string first (`"70,90,50"`) and then `"70,90,50"` can't be implicitly converted to a number, so the result is `NaN`. `NaN / 3` is `NaN` because any math operation with `NaN` results in `NaN`.

Finally, the last `grade >= 100` condition looks dodgy. It means you aren't handling `90...99`. You probably just want `default` (or `else`) there.

I assume you wanted to get the average grade instead, which you can do with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) (or a simple loop):

```
const grade = [70, 90, 50].reduce((a, b) => a + b) / 3;
```

So doing that and using `switch (true)`:

```js
const grade = [70, 90, 50].reduce((a, b) => a + b) / 3;
switch (true) {
    case grade < 60:
        console.log("F");
        break;

    case grade >= 60 && grade < 70:
        console.log("D");
        break;

    case grade >= 70 && grade < 80:
        console.log("C");
        break;

    case grade >= 80 && grade < 90:
        console.log("B");
        break;

    default:
        console.log("Congrats on your A!");
}
```

You don't need those `grade >= 60 &&` and such, since each `case` label is tested in source code order and the first one wins.

```js
const grade = [70, 90, 50].reduce((a, b) => a + b) / 3;
switch (true) {
    case grade < 60:
        console.log("F");
        break;

    case grade < 70:
        console.log("D");
        break;

    case grade < 80:
        console.log("C");
        break;

    case grade < 90:
        console.log("B");
        break;

    default: // Made this default instead
        console.log("Congrats on your A!");
}
```

Or the `if...else if...else` version:

```js
const grade = [70, 90, 50].reduce((a, b) => a + b) / 3;
if (grade < 60) {
    console.log("F");
} else if (grade < 70) { // 
    console.log("D");
} else if (grade < 80) {
    console.log("C");
} else if (grade < 90) {
    console.log("B");
} else {
    console.log("Congrats on your A!");
}
```